# How can i change my default editor to atom in BansenLabs Linux?

Tags: linux, atom-editor

First of all, i need to say that my english is bad, and i am novice in Linux.

I have installed BansenLabs Linux, but by default, it comes with Geany as default text editor.
I did not want it, so i uninstalled Geany, and installed Atom. But how can i set Atom to my default text editor? I tried finding help on internet, but did not find anything that helps me.  (so when i press Super+e hotkey or open "Text Editor" in menu, atom will open) Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the forums, Rakhm.

If I remember correctly, BunsenLabs is based off Debian.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Type in `update-alternatives --list editor` and hit enter.
3. Find the path to the text editor.
4. Type `update-alternatives --set editor /path/to/the/chosen/editor` and hit enter.

EDIT: if step 2. doesn't work, you might have to use `update-alternatives --list`.

Comment: here's the output of `update-alternatives --list editor`: `/bin/nano/` `/usr/bin/vim.tiny/` But when i try to write `update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/atom` it gives an error that atom is not registered as an alternative to the text editor. How can i register atom as an alternative to text editor?

Comment: I see. Does Bunsen come with `thunar` as the default file manager? If so, you can right click on the text file you want to edit and set `atom` as the default text editor. You could also try editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` but ***remember to back up any file you are making changes to before editing!***

Comment: Yeah, but i have another target. So when you open a menu (or press Win+E), geany should open. But how can i change it, so atom opens instead of Geany? @telometto

P.S. By the way, great thanks for help.

Comment: I imagine that something in a configuration file needs to be changed. Unfortunately, I do not use OB myself, but maybe [this article](https://medium.com/daniels-tech-world/how-to-add-custom-keybindings-in-openbox-29a97088abae) could help solve your issue?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for help.

Comment: Wasn't much of help, unfortunately. Did the article solve anything?

Comment: To add Atom do the `update-alternatives` editors list use the following command: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/atom 100`. It should also set Atom as the default editor.